# google analytics track returning user

Tags: google-analytics

As we know that Google Analytic provides a way(Drop off rate) to find the users  who visited the page and never come back.

I am looking for a solution to track a user who logged in the website with "Remember me" option and then he closes out the browser and again he comes back. I.e to track the users who closes the browser and he comes back to the website again after opening the browser.
We would be able to provide the user_id to GA in this case to track the particular user.

Is it doable in Google Analytic.

Here are the details of my problem

Lets assume that i logged in to the website with "Remember Me".
I visited some of the pages and then i closed my browser. 
Again i came back,Since i logged in with "Remember Me" i will be logged in by default. 
Now i visited some of the pages lets assume 5 pages. In my reports I want these 5 pages to be tracked. 
Thanks

Comment: He will be recognized as a recurring user in any case (unless he has deleted his cookies in which case the remember me-option will probably fail, too). The user_id  feature is intended to recognize authenticated users across different devices, so this is not exactly your use case. Can you clarify what do you expect to see in your reports ? E.g. if you wanted to see how many people clicked the remember-me option you could set a visitor-scope custom dimension on a click event and build a custom report around that.

Comment: Thanks Pierstorff for reply,

Below is the details of problem

lets assume that i logged in to the website with "Remember Me".
I visited some of the pages and then i closed my browser.
Again i came back,Since i logged in with "Remember Me" i will be logged in by default.
Now i visited some of the pages lets assume 5 pages.
In my reports I want these 5 pages to be tracked.

Let me know if this explanation is ok.

Thanks